# Lynx file "/etc/lynx.lss" is not available

Tags: ssh, cron, cpanel, lynx

using cpanel server, setting a simple "lynx http://www.domain.com/script.php" command gives following error and I am unable to understand it.

> Lynx file "/etc/lynx.lss" is not available.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the SHELL.
You can solve this problem via two ways:

1] I simply changed the sentence:
   SHELL="/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell"
   in /var/spool/cron/account
   to SHELL="/bin/bash"

2] You can copy file /etc/lynx.lss
   to directory: /home/virtfs/account/etc

Both worked for me !

Wilhelm

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty (or not) style sheet file in a directory where you have write access, then explicitly point to that file on the lynx command-line:

lynx -lss=/path/to/my/lynx.lss ...

Answer (score 0):

I enabled shell access for the account and it started working. The above answer seems to assume you have access to the entire server and can modify those files, if so then just enable shell access and you are set, but if you are on a shared hosting account basic cpanel and ftp access you may not be able to do it. Ask you hosting company if you can have shell access. Then decide what you can do depending on the answer they give you.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question? The answer above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by follow below process :-

```
Open this file
```

> root@server [~]# vi /var/cpanel/exim.conf.deps

```
and append below entries and save it.
```

> /etc/lynx.lss